# How can re.sub() mutate immutable Python strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, object, immutability

Here, string `flight_details` string is changed but its id does not change, below is the code and its output:

```
import re

flight_details = "Flight Savana Airlines a2134"
print(id(flight_details))

print(re.sub(r"Flight", r"Plane", flight_details))
print(id(flight_details))

print(re.sub(r"Plane", r"Akash", flight_details))
print(id(flight_details))
```

Output:

```
27264016
Plane Savana Airlines a2134
27264016
Flight Savana Airlines a2134
27264016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id(flight_details)` returns the same value after the called to `re.sub` because
`re.sub` does not change the value of the string you pass into it (`flight_details`). It returns a new string.

For example:

```
import re

flight_details = "Flight Savana Airlines a2134"
print(flight_details)
print(id(flight_details))

re.sub(r"Flight", r"Plane", flight_details)
print(flight_details)
print(id(flight_details))

flight_details = re.sub(r"Flight", r"Plane", flight_details)
print(flight_details)
print(id(flight_details))
```

Output:

```
Flight Savana Airlines a2134
1442959741216
Flight Savana Airlines a2134
1442959741216
Plane Savana Airlines a2134
1442959741456
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: but what about the immutability of strings.  as I was told when we try to change a string we end up creating a new string object.

Comment: String are definitely immutable. When you do flight_details = re.sub(r"Flight", r"Plane", flight_details), the original string is discarded and now flight_details refers to a brand new string object. The original string object has not changed at all. flight_details no longer refers to it, and Python's garbage collector should eventually remove it from memory.

Comment: Ohh I got my mistake! , THANK YOU!